# Merge irregular time series data

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have data_VOC_A and data_VOC_B are hourly data sets, however they are irregular so when I merge two data sets I want to fill the blank cells w NA.

```
  #data frames


        data_VOC_A <-structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("09.09.2011 21:54", 
"09.09.2011 22:59"), class = "factor"), hexane = c(0, 0), benzene = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0", 
"4.4"), class = "factor"), toluene = c(2.2, 2.6)), .Names = c("Date", 
"hexane", "benzene", "toluene"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

    data_VOC_B<-structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("09.09.2011 21:54", 
"09.09.2011 22:59"), class = "factor"), ethane = c(14.4, 868.9
), propane = c(6.4, 32.1), isobutane = c(1.7, 2), n.butane = c(3.1, 
3), isopentane = c(5.6, 3), n.pentane = c(1.4, 2.4)), .Names = c("Date", 
"ethane", "propane", "isobutane", "n.butane", "isopentane", "n.pentane"
), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

#merge data frames 
d2<- merge.data.frame(data_VOC_A,data_VOC_B, by='Date', all=TRUE)
```

There is a problem with the merged data frame (d2)'s timeline.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the expected result is. Can we have an example?

Comment: if you get your two time fields to match then it should be as simple as using a left_join()

Comment: @GGamba I just added the expected output. Aaron, yes, I want to match two time fields but also I want to keep the time serious regular. So, it is like filling an empty time frame with the available data sets.

Comment: Is your code cut off? Where is your merge attempt? Did you try the outer join merge, specifically with `all=TRUE` argument.

Comment: I have tried several ways, I did not want to add and confuse people. For example, MD<- merge.data.frame(data_VOC_A,data_VOC_B, by='Date', all=TRUE)
This output merges the two data sets but there are errors on "Date" column.  Another method I tried, I converted the data frames to zoo objects, but this also did not give meaningful results: MD<- as.zoo(merge(as.timeSeries(data_VOC_A), as.timeSeries(data_VOC_B)))

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to correspond to the inputs provided.  Also the data frames seem to have data in the headers.  Please show a consistent example, ix your inputs and explain how to get the output from the input.

Comment: I updated the text.